# UPDATE table1.argument1 basing on the value of table3.argument3

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

**table1** is connected to **table2** using key1

**table2** is connected to **table3** using key2

So table2 has 2 foreign keys. One if used to connect to table1. Second one is used to connect to table3.

I need to update **table1.argument1** basing on the value of **table3.argument3**

I tried this:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.argument1 = <NEW_VALUE>
WHERE
   (SELECT table3.argument3 
   FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.key1=table3.key3) = <SOME_VALUE>;
```

It gives me an error.
I assume my mistake is in avoiding table2. Is there an easier way?
Also is there a way that avoids subqueries?

**UPDATE**

---

I think I'm misunderstanding the question. 
Please see the schema below(I removed all the unnecessary entires)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `company`.`employee` (
`ssn` CHAR(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`salary` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`dno` BIGINT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ssn`),
 INDEX `dno` (`dno` ASC),
 CONSTRAINT `employee_ibfk_2`
 FOREIGN KEY (`dno`)
 **REFERENCES `company`.`department` (`dnumber`),**
```

---

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `company`.`department` (
 `dnumber` BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `mgrssn` CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dnumber`),
  INDEX `mgrssn` (`mgrssn` ASC),`
  FOREIGN KEY (`mgrssn`)
  **REFERENCES `company`.`employee` (`ssn`))**
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

---

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `company`.`project` (
  `pnumber` BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dnum` BIGINT NOT NULL,
   INDEX `dnum` (`dnum` ASC),`
   FOREIGN KEY (`dnum`)
   REFERENCES `company`.`department` (`dnumber`))
```

the question is : **Give every employee on project  a   salary.**

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: If tables 1 and 3 are not directly related, why do even attempt to join them directly?

Comment: First problem: `table` is used twice with no aliases, so there is ambiguity.  Second problem: The value you are comparing to `<SOME VALUE>` comes from the left side of an outer join.  So what does the join give you?  You are not actually using `table3`.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: "You can't specify target table 'table3' for UPDATE in FROM clause "

Comment: I assumed that if there is connection between table2 - table1 and table2 - table3, there is connection between table3 and table1. Now I get it.. it's not right. Should I join all 3 of them?

Comment: Couldn't this just become `UPDATE table1 SET table1.argument = <NEW_VALUE> WHERE argument = <SOME_VALUE>`?

Comment: I don't think this is valid syntax.  To do the `UPDATE <table> SET x = y WHERE` form, I think you can only reference one table.  To do a join, I believe you need the `FROM` syntax like `UPDATE t1 SET argument = <NEW_VALUE> FROM table1 t1 WHERE ...`.

Comment: Since you revised the code, you switched to selecting from `table3`.  `NULL` will never equal anything (including `NULL`), so this should be an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

"I need to update table1.argument1 basing on the value of table3.argument3"

Instead of selecting table1.argument you need to select table3.argument.

The best I can think of is you need to select and get the table2.key2 first.

Try this:

```
SELECT table2.key1 AS KEY_VALUE
       FROM table3 JOIN table2 on table2.key2 = table3.key2 where table3.argument = <SOME_VALUE>

UPDATE table1
SET table1.argument = <NEW_VALUE>
WHERE
  table1.key1 = <KEY_VALUE>
```

From your example:

```
SELECT table2.SCHOOL_ID AS KEY_VALUE
           FROM table3 JOIN table2 on table2.PROJECT_ID = table3.PROJECT_ID where table3.PROJECT_NAME = <SOME_VALUE>

UPDATE table1
    SET table1.GRADE = <NEW_VALUE>
    WHERE
       SCHOOL_ID = <KEY_VALUE>
```

Comment: This still makes no sense. It's like saying "Update a field on a table, where some unrelated field is some arbitrary value". It's crazy bananas.

Comment: From the structure I see it didnt make sense also. But I am just trying to help him looking the at the question. Believe me there I have seen wilder table structure than this

Comment: Why join to `table2`?  If `key1` equals `key2` and `key2` equals `key3`, then `key1` equals `key3`.

Comment: Ok. Let's try this: we have student table that has a grade parameter; each student is connected to a school(using school_ID) and each school is connected to a project(using projectID). I want to increase a student's grade if he/she did the project number projectID.

Comment: @Brandon My bad typo mistake. Because without naming easier to get confuse

Comment: Martono Halim,  still getting the same error. Error code:1093

Comment: I see, this is totally wrong. Will delete this answer later. Sorry it makes more confuses

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have your statement all backwards. In mysql an `UPDATE` using criteria from another table takes the form:

```
UPDATE
FROM <table>
INNER JOIN <table2>
    ON <table>.<field> = <table2>.<field>
SET <table>.<field2> = <some value>
WHERE <table2>.<somefield> = something...
```

In your case assuming that you can join T1 to T3 directly (you suggest that you shouldn't but I have no way to verify your schema):

```
UPDATE 
FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table3 ON
        table1.key1 = table3.key3
SET table1.argument1 = <?>
WHERE table3.argument3 = <?>
```

If you are just trying to set table1's argument1 value to table3's argument3 value where the keys match then:

```
UPDATE 
FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table3 ON
        table1.key1 = table3.key3
SET table1.argument1 = table3.argument3
```

### Updated to match update on OP's question

You say that you want every employee on a project to have a salary. The schema suggests that an employee is not on a project, but rather is part of a department, and the department is on a project. I assume then that if the department is on a project, then the employees of the department are all on the project.

Your update query to give everyone the same salary if they are on ANY project would look something like:

```
UPDATE 
FROM employee
    LEFT JOIN project ON
        employee.dno = project.dnum
SET employee.salary = <whatever salary>
WHERE project.dnum IS NOT NULL
```

Your update query to give people the same salary if they are on a specific project would be:

```
UPDATE 
FROM employee
    INNER JOIN project ON
        employee.dno = project.dnum
SET employee.salary = <whatever salary>
WHERE project.pnumber = <your project ID>
```

Comment: Note: If doing an equality match on a column from the right side of a left join, you will never match rows that didn't pass the join criteria.  You may as well use an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: *Unless you wanted to check for instances where the join criteria failed to find a match.

Comment: Then you would not do an equality test on your `WHERE` clause.  You would do an `IS NULL` test.

Comment: This inner join looks solid maybe can try on this